# What does this method mean? What's <V> after static?

Tags: java

I was just going through some code and I see the following method

```
  public static <V> Set<V> newHashSet() {
    return new HashSet<V>();
  }
```

What does `<V>` after static keyword mean? and what does `Set<V>` mean? I've used set with type String etc. but what's `<V>`?

Comment: Look for *[Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics)*.

Comment: doesn't <?> denote generic?

Comment: `<?>` denotes a wildcard which technically means "? extends Object" if I know correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The V is used for generics. If you write

```
// ClassName is the class newHashSet is declared in
ClassName.<String>newHashSet();
```

it will work just as well as

```
ClassName.<Integer>newHashSet();
```

This way you can reuse this method for different types.
It's called generics.

Set is what the function returns.
Static means the function belongs to a class, not to an instance of the class.

Comment: Can I not just use newHashSet<?>

Comment: @Radiodef Minor syntax detail in fact.

Comment: I've corrected your syntax. In the future, when you write answers, you should make sure that it's correct yourself.

Answer (score -1):

it specifies a generic type to be used in this method. As the method is static, it will not use any generics specified for the class -- as there is no class, essentially, when it comes down to the compiler. So, for static methods that use generics, the generic type has to be declared in front of the return type.

Comment: *"As the method is static, it will not use any generics specified for the class"* Sorry, this makes no sense. I think you don't understand static and/or generics correctly, or I misunderstood you.

Comment: @m0skit0:  `class A<T> {  public static void foo(T t) { ; } }` will not compile, as type T is not known in method `foo`. (sorry, cannot format it better in a comment)

Comment: Ok I see, yes you're right. But this is not the question :)